BigQuery Data Transfer with Oracle DB: Runs ok when launched manually, fails when scheduled
We have set up a scheduled BigQuery transfer to transfer an Oracle table to BigQuery, like described here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/oracle-transfer.
The configuration is ok, because it runs okay when started manually.
However, when it's triggered in a scheduled job, it never works.
enter image description here
The only error we receive is
jsonPayload: {
message: "System error when starting to transfer asset ORCL/MYDB/XXXMYVIEW, try again later."
}
The summary says:
Transfer run failed with system error code UNKNOWN.
Attached you can find the full error entry.
enter image description here
Please advice, thanks!
Sebastian
